# How install Marlin file manager in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, marlin

I have follow tutorial from this [page](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/09/marlin-file-manager-is-now-available.html)

but i forgot, my ubuntu version is 15.04, so when i tried install marlin, this return `E: Unable to locate package marlin`

how can i install marlin ?

i want to make my folder view like Mac,,,column view

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the people who were maintaining Marlin are no longer doing so - there is no package available for Ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10, and no apparent development since September 2014

Comment: Maybe another package in Ubuntu 15.04 similar marlin?

Comment: @ihsansat Elementary OS's Files app looks great, although I don't personally like it because it removes a *lot* of great features.